# Замена в файле всех значений через POST

Tags: php

Покажите пожалуйста новичу самоучке, решение.
В файле 1.txt каждая строка имеет дату и значения (расписание работы) пример:

1. 06.03.2024*Alex
2. 07.03.2024*Petr

Я ети значения через цикл вношу в форму для редактирования

```
    $file=file('1.txt');
foreach($file as $line){
$line=trim($line);
$exp=explode("*",$line);
if(isset($exp[0])){
echo "<input type='name' name='id[]' value='$exp[1]'><br>";
}else{}
}
```

А дальше не знаю как етот массив из $_POST['id'] заменить каждый в свою строку, делал вот так.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$file=file('1.txt');
foreach($file as $line){
$line=trim($line);
$exp=explode("*",$line);
$post=$_POST['id'];
$replace[]=$exp[1];
$str=str_replace($replace,$post,$line);
echo $str;
}}
```

Но если я изменю например Alex и он найдет в другой дате то и там его заменит.

Comment: а зачем что-то заменять? просто записать в файл

Comment: График расписания, первые идет дата 06.03.2024*имя. Расписания работы кто и когда, этот график на целый год, следовательно имена нужно иногда нужно менять или переставлять. Поетому мне нужно сделать возможность заменить их после чего записать в файл.

Comment: ну так и записывайте. весь график. в чем проблема?

Comment: Отредактировал для наглядности что у меня выходит.

Comment: Я, наверное, непонятно пишу. Не надо ничего заменять. Надо просто записать информацию из формы обратно в файл.

Comment: но как? я неулавливаю суть. Вить в каждом поле у меня выводится имя а не целая строка з датой, иначе можна заменить случайно дату.

Comment: @Serg_rv https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: evgen_dev я имел ввиду реализацию. Если я запишу массив из POST где одни имена я в файл запишу одни имена, удалив все даты, даты используеться другой командой котовая формирует таблицу графика для того сначала строки и указываеться дата  кто когда работает. Если допустить что я в пост введу всю строку чтобы замена была корректной тогда модератор когда будет набирать фамилии непреднамеренно изменит год 2024 на 2023 тогда в таблице этой строки не будет, потому и не могу решить задачку как зделать дабы модератор менял только фамилии вить каждая строка отвечает за определенную дату.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю мне предлагаете в текстовую форму вложывать сразу всю строку: тобиш (07.03.2024*Alex) но если например ктото введет 2023 или забудет указать звездочку(07.03.2023 Alex) тогда этой даты в таблице не будет. Поэтому я предпологаю что должна меняться только значения (имя) после звездочки, дабы модератор набирал только имя и оно подставлялось или заменялось до этой даты. Простите пожалуйста если плохо доношу свою мысль, как я предпологаю реализацию.

Comment: Текстовый файл не подходит для данной задачи. Необходимо использовать базу данных.

Comment: @ВикторКарев с точки зрения задачи файл всегда заменит базу данных

Comment: как-то так в общем https://phpize.online/s/Q4

Comment: @Ипатьев
 Спасибо большое,

Comment: Можете написать ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое 'Ипатьев' за решение.

```
$file = file('1.txt');
foreach($file as $line){
    $line = trim($line);
    $exp = explode("*", $line);
    if(isset($exp[1])) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="date[]" value="'.htmlspecialchars($exp[0]).'" readonly>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="id[]" value="'.htmlspecialchars($exp[1]).'"><br>'.PHP_EOL;
   }
}

if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $result = '';
    foreach($_POST['date'] as $i => $date) {
        $result.= $date.'*'.$_POST['id'][$i].PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, я не просто так разделил эхо на две строки. Читать код гораздо удобнее, когда его видно. Во-вторых, я не просто так добавил htmlspecialchars, и убирать эту функцию не стоило. В-третьих, я не знаю, кто у вас там редактирует, может ясновидящие, но нормальному человеку желательно видеть дату, для которой он редактирует данные. И в-четвертых, я понятия не имею, зачем вам в текстовом файле тег `<br>`

Comment: Для моих целей читать его не нужно потому как мне нужно было найти решение, за что вам блогодарен. Я подганяю его для своих нужд, дату выводить мне лично не нужно так как все это дело будет визуально понятным тобиш в виде таблицы не только на вывод но и на ввод где дата будет статично в отдельной клетке! htmlspecialchars у меня все без него работает. br для розделения, мне сейчас так визуально понятен результат как в файле всместо одной строкой.

Comment: @Ипатьев Только сейчас заметил что в даного метода есть ограничение 500 строк. Тобиш если файл имел 730 строк после замены обрезает до 500. Есть ли возможность это исправить?

Comment: Max_input_vars.

Comment: @Ипатьев увеличивать max_input_vars с ростом кол-ва строк в файле, так себе решение... как по мне лучше уже сериализация на клиенте в тот же  json и отправка одним полем. имхо

Comment: А теперь представьте, что с этой страницей одновременно работают два менеджера. Один исправил дату в первой строке и отправил, второй исправил дату во второй строке и затёр исправления первого, поскольку в первой строке отправились старые данные. Отправляться должны только изменённые данные, а не все.

Comment: @ВикторКарев а как это поможет от того, что оба исправят одну строчку?

Comment: @Ипатьев а это и не нужно. Всегда в подобных случаях считается, что "кто последний, тот и папа".